# How to perform a put and delete requests

Tags: express, mongoose

Below is my code for making get and post requests for my own app. I am stacked in put (for edit or update ) and delete routes can not perform them to do the job.

May anybody can help me with the possible codes?

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const requireAuth = require('../middlewares/requireAuth');

const Order = mongoose.model('Order');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(requireAuth);

router.get('/order', async (req, res) => {
  const orders = await Order
    .find({ userId: req.user._id });

  res.send(orders);
});

router.post('/order', async (req, res) => {
  const
    { pharmacyName, item1, quantity1, bonus1,
      item2, quantity2, bonus2, item3, quantity3, bonus3, item4, quantity4, bonus4,
      item5, quantity5, bonus5
    } = req.body;

  if (!pharmacyName || !item1 || !quantity1 || !bonus1) {
    return res.status(422)
      .send({ error: 'Some Fields are missed please fill all' });
  }

  try {
    const order = new Order({
      pharmacyName, item1, quantity1, bonus1,
      item2, quantity2, bonus2, item3, quantity3, bonus3, item4, quantity4, bonus4,
      item5, quantity5, bonus5, userId: req.user._id
    });
    await order.save();
    res.send(order);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(422)
      .send({ error: err.message })
  }
});

router.put('/order/_id', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Got a PUT request at /user')
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please use that code router.delete('/order/:id',  (req, res) => {
    res.send('Got a delete request at /user')
  })

Answer (score 0):

```
    router.put(`/order/:_id` , (req, res) => {
    Order.findById(req.params._id , (err, order) => {

       if (order) {
           order.pharmacyName = req.body.pharmacyName;
           order.item1 = req.body.item1;
           order.quantity1 = req.body.quantity1;
           order.bonus1 = req.body.bonus1;
           order.item2 = req.body.item2;
           order.quantity2 = req.body.quantity2;
           order.bonus2 = req.body.bonus2;
           order.item3 = req.body.item3;
           order.quantity3 = req.body.quantity3;
           order.bonus3 = req.body.bonus3;
           order.item4 = req.body.item4;
           order.quantity4 = req.body.quantity4;
           order.bonus4 = req.body.bonus4;
           order.item5 = req.body.item5;
           order.quantity5 = req.body.quantity5;
           order.bonus5 = req.body.bonus5;
           order.notes = req.body.notes;
           order.save();
           res.send(order);
       } else {
           res.status(422).send({error : err.message});
       }
    })
});

router.delete('/:_id', (req, res) => {

   Order.findByIdAndRemove(req.params._id, (err, order) => {
       if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
       res.status(200).send(`Order ${req.params._id} has been deleted Successfuly`);
   })
});
```